# Sort is not working in D3 hierarchy even if I change a - b to b - a

Tags: javascript, d3.js

this is my code:

```
var data2 = {
  name: "A1",
  children: [
    {
      name: "C9",
      value: 600,
    },
    {
      name: "C8",
      value: 110,
    },
    {
      name: "C7",
      value: 120,
    },
    {
      name: "C6",
      value: 130,
    },
    {
      name: "C5",
      value: 140,
    },
    {
      name: "C4",
      value: 150,
    },
  ],
};

var root = d3
  .hierarchy(data2)
  .sum(function (d: any) {
    return d.size;
  })
  .sort(function (a: any, b: any) {
    return b.value - a.value;
  });

var packLayout = d3.pack();
packLayout.size([400, 400]);
packLayout.padding(20);

root.sum((d: any) => {
  return d.value;
});

packLayout(root);

var packNodes = d3
  .select("#pack g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(root.descendants())
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", (d: any) => {
    console.log("transform d: ", d);
    return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")";
  });

packNodes
  .append("circle")
  .classed("the-node", true)
  .attr("r", (d: any) => d.r)
  .style("fill", "rgba(255,255,255,0.2)")
  .style("stroke", "#2f2f2f");

packNodes
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .attr("dy", 4)
  .attr("dx", -8)
  .text((d) => (d.children === undefined ? d.data.name : ""));
```

i have been experimenting with switching sort a - b and b - a but nothing works, ideally what i simply want to do is like this: http://jsfiddle.net/UZLVY/ but it's in older version, i am new to d3 and i want to do it in v6

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `b.value` and `a.value`, it has to be `b.data.value` and `a.data.value`. As the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy) says:

> The returned node and each descendant has the following properties:
>
> node.data - the associated data, as specified to the constructor.

Here is the working demo:

```js
var data2 = {
  name: "A1",
  children: [{
      name: "C9",
      value: 600,
    },
    {
      name: "C8",
      value: 110,
    },
    {
      name: "C7",
      value: 120,
    },
    {
      name: "C6",
      value: 130,
    },
    {
      name: "C5",
      value: 140,
    },
    {
      name: "C4",
      value: 150,
    },
  ],
};

var root = d3
  .hierarchy(data2)
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.data.value - a.data.value;
  });

console.log(root.children)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hello, can u make a codesandbox? i tried it just now, it's not working :(

Comment: If you `console.log(root.data)` it still shows the original unsorted node

Comment: @Parzival that's expected, the `root.data` is just the original dataset, it's not mutated by hierarchy methods: only the children are sorted, as the API clearly says: *"Sorts the children of this node"*. Also, what you have in your answer is just a basic `Array.prototype.sort`, which has nothing to do with the text you quoted.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks for the message. I thought the OP needed a sorted `root.data`, so I'm just want to say you need to apply sort before you create the hierarchical layout. You're right, the `sort` from the docs is irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

You need to apply `sort` before creating a hierarchical structure.

The following should work<sup>1</sup>:

```js
var data2 = {
  name: "A1",
  children: [{
      name: "C9",
      value: 600,
    },
    {
      name: "C8",
      value: 110,
    },
    {
      name: "C7",
      value: 120,
    },
    {
      name: "C6",
      value: 130,
    },
    {
      name: "C5",
      value: 140,
    },
    {
      name: "C4",
      value: 150,
    },
  ],
};


data2 = data2.children.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.value - a.value;
});

var root = d3
  .hierarchy(data2);

console.log(root.data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```

<sub>1: ignore the css, just for demo purposes</sub>

Comment: hi, thanks, i am looking at: http://jsfiddle.net/UZLVY/ i cant convert it to v6, can u help me?